# A collection that is an algebra and countable additivity

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $X$ be a countable and infinite set and $$\mathcal{F}:=\{A\subset X;\#A<\infty\ \text{or}\ \#A^C<\infty\}.$$
>
> (a) Show that $\mathcal{F}$ is an algebra.
>
> (b) Given $A\in\mathcal{F}$, defines $$\mu(A):=\left\lbrace\begin{array}{c}0,\ \text{if}\ A\ \text{is finite}\\1,\ \text{if}\ A^C\ \text{is finite}\end{array}\right..$$ Show that $\mu$ is finitelly additive, but isn't necessarily countable additive.

I'm with some problems in (b). Taking the finite and disjoint family $\{A_j\}_{j=1}^n\subset\mathcal{F}$, if $A_j$ is finite, for each $j\in\{1,...,n\}$, is easy to see that $\mu$ is finitelly additive, but i'm stacked in the other cases. Since $\{A_j\}$ is 2-2 disjoint, if we have $A_{j_0}^C$ finite, for some $j_0\in\Bbb{N}$, we get $$A_k\subset A_{j_0}^C, \forall k\in\{1,...,n\}\setminus\{j_0\},$$ hence $$\bigcup_{\begin{array}{c}j=1\\j\ne j_0\end{array}}^{n}A_j\subset A_{j_0}^C,$$ so $\bigcup_{\begin{array}{c}j=1\\j\ne j_0\end{array}}^{n}A_j$ is finite.

So, how to conclude what we want? This looks very confused to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other case is that one of the $A_j$, say $A_{j_0}$ has a finite complement. Then the complement of $\bigcup_{k=1}^nA_k$  is finite hence $\mu\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^nA_k\right)=1$. It suffices to show that there is no $j_1\in\{1,\dots,n\}\setminus \{j_0\}$ such that $A_{j_1}$ has a finite complement. Otherwise, it would mean that $A_{j_0}^c$ and $A_{j_1}^c$ are both finite, hence so would be their union, which is actually $X$.

Comment: Thankyou! I didn't realize the fact that since $A_{j_0}$ and $A_{j_1}$ are disjoint, we have that its complements reunion is the entire space $X$.

Answer (score 2):

Enumerate $X= \{x_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ and choose $A_n = \{x_n\}$. Then $\bigcup_n A_n = X$ but $\mu(A_n) = 0$ for all $n$.

I'm not sure if I'm specifically answering your question.